# Should I install visual studio 12

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm doing a project with a couple of other guys who have vs10, will it hurt if just I upgrade to vs12. Will it hurt when we all check in on svn? Will everything still be compatible as far as wpf, mvc, etc.. goes. Should I be aware of anything about the new visual studio 2012?

Comment: Every new version the last few release cycles has gotten a little better about working safely with the prior version. This is an area Mircosoft is trying to address, in part to improve it's open source/distributed development story. However, there's no guarantee yet that you won't run into trouble somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would keep a similar environment to everyone else working on the project - either all go 2012 or all stay 2010.

Not to say that there are or are not known issues with working between the two environments, but why introduce possible problems when you're going to work with the lowest possible common denominator anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Using VS2012 and VS2010 seems to work flawlessly, so far. I installed it a month ago when it became available on MSDN. I've worked on several problems since then without any compatibility issues. Rather worryingly though, we've come across an issue where a linq to entities query works fine on a machine without .net 4.5, but fails on a machine with .net 4.5, despite the project targeting .net 4.0. A colleague is looking at this at the moment, so I don't have any more details